# Find average number of orders per customer in last three years?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out average number of orders per customer in last three years.
 i am trying this query:

```
SELECT Name,SalesOrderDetailID, AVG(OrderQty) AS Average
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail  
inner join Production.Product 
        on Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = Production.Product.ProductID
GROUP BY SalesOrderDetailID, Name
having(year(ModifiedDate)) > DATEADD(yy, -1, CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)));
```

But i am having this error:

> Column 'Sales.SalesOrderDetail.ModifiedDate' is invalid 
>   in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either 
>   an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do *you* mean by "average number of orders per customer"?  Sample data and an explanation of what defines a customer would also be helpful.

Comment: The criteria should likely belong in a `WHERE` clause rather than a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: What about the error don't you understand here?

Answer (score 2):

The average number of orders per customer is a single value -- the total number of orders divided by the number of customers.

Hence, I would expect something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sod.order_id) * 1.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(DISTINCT sod.customer_id), 0)
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail sod
WHERE sod.ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE());
```

Comment: @Programming_lover . . . If that is the case, then you have no customers.